# Sony Vaio BIOS Setup not Working?

Tags: bios, operating-systems, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio E-series (VPCEA22EA) laptop. Yesterday, while I was starting up my laptop as usual, it showed the password error saying:

> Password you entered is incorrect

I forcefully shut it down and again started it up but the laptop showed:

> Operating system not found

I tried to enter into the BIOS setup by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd>, and <kbd>ESC</kbd> keys separately but it did not work.

Comment: Do you have a `Startup Repair Disc` ?

Answer (score 3):

To enter BIOS in Sony Vaio, you need to press ASSIST button when the computer is off. The computer will power on and show a menu with an option to set up BIOS.

Comment: save my day man.

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple issues.

First, 
I assume you have forgot the BIOS password. If that is the case then contact Sony support. They'll have few backdoor BIOS passwords that might help you. 
If you're sure that you're entering the correct password, then try to reset the BIOS by removing the CMOS battery.

OR

Follow the steps below :

1) Unplug AC adaptor.
2) Remove the battery.
3) Press and hold the power button for about 2 mins.

Possibly you could have your BIOS reset after this procedure. Some BIOS passwords don't reset even after removing the CMOS battery.

Second,
I assume you have exceeded the max number of tries to enter the BIOS by entering wrong passwords, it could have wiped out the OS and other files as a security measure.

OR

simply, your HDD might have loose contact or corrupted.

> *NOTE* : **DO NOTHING** if your machine is under warranty. Contact Sony
>   Support.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may occur if one or more of the following conditions are true:

a)   The basic input/output system (BIOS) does not detect the hard disk.
b)   The hard disk is damaged.
c)   Sector 0 of the physical hard disk drive has an incorrect or malformed master boot record (MBR).

Note  Some third-party programs or disk corruption can damage an MBR.
d)   An incompatible partition is marked as Active.
e)   A partition that contains the MBR is no longer active.

Sometimes, system starts after reset by pressing `Alt`, `Ctrl` & `Delete` keys simultaneously.
You can also try with the repair disc provided by the **Sony** .

You may find the following links useful to solve your problem:

> http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/118615-my-sony-vaio-crashed-and-now-i-see-operating-system-not-found-during-boot

&

> http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/operating-system-not-found-windows-7-sony-vaio/575e2fdc-a655-4a37-9a26-1bb63fbb5814